# Sharing one header/footer between layouts in NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have two layouts and one header and footer that I want to share between the two. I want to reduce duplication html markup. As it is  right now I have to import the header into both layouts. The problem here is that the header has state, and when that layout changes, the state seemingly gets reset. An example being using something like vuetify tabs.

Edit: Better example.

```
header.vue
|
|_ _ layout 1 (with video)
|
|_ _ layout 2 (with parallax)
|
footer.vue
```

Both layouts have different body setups, but the same header. The problem with layouts is that switching from one layout to another causes the client to render everything again, which I don't necessarily want because it looks janky.

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/layouts#default-layout default layout will help! Place common HTML over there.

Answer (score 0):

As commented ([link to documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/layouts#default-layout)) you can have header and footer in one even with different states.

Eg: Here I have a layout with header and footer. The page uses Vuetify and shows a v-navigation-drawer on mobile and v-toolbar on a PC.
I'm going to show the v-navigation-drawer and v-toolbar if I'm on the Home-page ( v-if="$route.path === '/'"): (layout/default.vue)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-if="$route.path === '/'"
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant="miniVariant"
      :clipped="clipped"
      fixed
      app
      disable-resize-watcher
      :key="navigation_drawer_key"
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile
          v-for="(link, i) in links"
          :key="i"
          :to="link.to"
          router
          exact
        >
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ link.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title v-text="link.title" />
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar
      v-if="$route.path === '/'"
      :clipped-left="clipped"
      scroll-off-screen
      fixed
    >
      <v-toolbar-side-icon
        @click="drawer = !drawer"
        class="hidden-md-and-up"
      />
      <div v-for="(link, i) in links" :key="i" class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn
          flat
          :to="link.to"
        >
          {{ link.title }}
        </v-btn>
      </div>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer>
      This is my footer
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      clipped: false,
      drawer: false,
      fixed: false,
      links: [
        {
          icon: 'home',
          title: 'Home',
          to: '/',
        },
        {
          icon: 'apps',
          title: 'products',
          to: '/products',
        },
        {
          icon: 'info',
          title: 'Contact us',
          to: '/contact',
        },
      ],
      navigation_drawer_key: 0,
      miniVariant: false,
      right: true,
      rightDrawer: false
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

Comment: If I have two layouts that have different body structures but require the same header I still essentially have to implement the header in layout 2 (unless there's something I'm missing). Basically what I'm looking at is something similar to how wordpress does layouts (one header/footer) inject into all the templates/layouts of the other pages with no duplication. Something akin to a parent layout (which holds the header/footer) and a child footer (with the differing body layout). The only other way I can see this happening is with child routes, but that doesn't fit my use case.

Comment: And it's not possible to make the header as a component and import it into the two layouts and use Vuex for the shared states?

Comment: It's totally possible, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. For a better description basically I want to accomplish the following, but it's seeming more unlikely this is possible with nuxt layouts. I updated my question with a better example. The reason is that it appears (at least to me) that when the layout is changed, all the components under the layout are rendered again, so basically I'm rendering the header again with duplicate html (which I don't necessarily need because I'm using the same header and footer).

Comment: From the new edit I would suggest having one layout in the layout folder and write the two layouts in to that main layout like this: 
`<template><v-app><Header /><Video v-if="SomeCondition" /><Parallax v-if="!SomeCondition" /><nuxt /><Footer /></v-app></template>`

I'm not taking any states to account in this, so if this is not what you had in mind can you share what kind of states you are sharing between the components?

Answer (score 0):

You create component for each of header and footer and use it in your layout and use vuex to store states and changed in it for not resetting state:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: It's not just the state, when layouts are swapped you get this weird flickering effect as well. Basically I want the same header for both layouts, but I dont want to duplicate the code.